# finding factors

Tags: factoring

How can i quickly find the factors of a particular number?

Find the number of different factors of 1800 and 3003?

This being the question , for 3003 i first found out its prime factors and then i could find the factors by multiplying each other.......but this was  a tedious method and when i started doing it for 1800 ,i ended up dumbstruck!

So, plz help me by giving a quick way of doing this!

Comment: It is best to use [divisibility rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_rule) if you want to do it by hand. For computing, finding efficient factoring algorithms for computers has always been a challenge.

Comment: But it takes a lot of time yet! going about the divisibility rule , i am gonna end with only factors till 20 and likewise , i won't sit there calculating  for 36  factors as it is for 1800!

Comment: If $n=p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_k^{a_k}$, where the $p_i$ are distinct primes, then the number of positive factors of $n$ is $(a_1+1)(a_2+1)\cdots (a_k+1)$.

Comment: For example $1800=2^3\cdot 3^2\cdot 5^2$, so the number of positive factors is $(3+1)(2+1)(2+1)$.

Comment: wow..........Thank u so much........i have been striving for this for past two hours !!! Where did u get this from?

Comment: What factorization did you get for $3003$? And what do you think the number of factors is? As to where I got it, it is a standard result. The proof is not hard, I can if you wish sketch it for you.

Comment: sorry sorry......i got it now......... i'm so sorry for being hasty! Thnks a lot ..........i appreciate ur help!

Comment: You should get $3003=3\cdot 7\cdot 11\cdot 13$, so $2^4$ factors. Don't forget that $1$ and $3003$ are factors of $3003$.

Comment: yeah that is exactly what i missed......... thats why i got it wrong!

Answer (score 2):

If $n=p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}\cdots p_k^{a_k}$, where the $p_i$ are distinct primes, then the number of (positive) factors of $n$ is
$$(a_1+1)(a_2+1)\cdots (a_k+1).$$

For example, if $n=1800$, then since $1800=2^3\cdot 3^2\cdot 5^2$, the number of positive factors of $n$ is $(3+1)(2+1)(2+1)$.

*Remarks:* $1.$ The above formula is easy to use if we know the prime power factorization of $n$. However, if $n$ is large, then finding that factorization can be computationally difficult.

$2.$ Here is an outline of a proof. We are trying to make a factor $d$ of $n$. We first look at $p_1$ and decide how many $p_1$'s $d$ will get. The choices are $0$ $p_1$'s, or $1$, or $2$, and so on up to $a_k$, a total of $a_1+1$ choices. For *every* such choice, there are $a_2+1$ ways to decide how many $p_2$'s the factor $d$ will get. And so on.